# How to inject a command with spaces in an url?

Tags: javascript, linux, security

I tried the following but was getting 
"1 new email"

http://url:portNo/search?name=%3Bmail&&ls%7C&field2=1084&matnr=2391068

It means mail has been executed but not ls.

The page submit is through a java script submit form which is doing a string replace / /g with ""

I tried replacing the line and even removing it but is producing the same result.

How do I inject commands like "echo p | mail"

Note : using " doesn't work.

Comment: URL encoding...?

Comment: Yes! you are right

Comment: URL encoding has nothing to do with javascript, linux or security. Why didn't you put also Windows, Mac OS/X, MVS/ESA, VMS, Digital-UX, UNIX, etc?  you should replace all the question tags with simply `url encoding` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use spaces in an url, you need to escape them, using the alternative `%20` sequence.  There is a legacy alternate, that consists on using the `+` sign in place of a space.... but I think nowadays it is strongly discouraged.